# Strange Brasero Problem

Tags: 12.04, iso, dvd, burning, brasero

I was trying to burn a copy of the Zorin OS iso to a DVD+R in Brasero. It started out fine, and then it said "Ejected Medium" and ejected the disc.  Then it said that an error ocurred. Why is this happening? I've heard there's a problem with Brasero and Sony discs, but I'm using a Memorex one.  I'm kind of a noob to linux, so if you answer, please make it simple.

Answer (score 1):

ancient question, but still came across this problem on Xenial, so here is the solution:

```
apt install brasero-cdrkit
```

Comment: This appears to be a working solution for half the affected people - I'm in the other half. See discussion here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/brasero/+bug/783918

Answer (score 0):

Brasero is known for making errors, unfortunately. It is not the best software available for burning DVDs and CDs.

I've burned about 100 CDs in Ubuntu Linux and I would suggest using **K3b** which just rocks :)

Comment: K3b is more feature-rich, but I'm not quite so sure about the bugginess aspect. I once had to use Brasero in a KDE distro 'cause K3b was letting me down. Also, K3b pulls along with it a whole bunch of kde lib packages which are not needed for anything except K3b. So, K3b may be a solution in this case, but not a perfect one.

Comment: @Pavel As far as I know there is not a perfect solution for this problem. I answered solely from my and others' experience. I found myself stuck with Brasero while K3b solved my problems.

Comment: I didn't deny yours could be the solution, only pointed out the limitations.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to set burning speed manually rather than letting Brasero determine the speed automatically ("max speed"). Worked for me once.